# How to implement material editText red bottom highlighting on error?

Tags: android, material-design

As far as I know, Google's AppCompat library does not always get methods to implement material features, so, most of the effects are to be implemented manually

In fact, the question is how to change the bottom `AppCompatEditText`'s line colour programmatically? Is there a method to change it or do I just have to keep several background images for each widget's state?

A little offtopic: what is that bottom line? Is it a pre-generated ninepatch or something like XML drawable?

UPD: one of the solutions is this, but it does not work on ICS

```
EditText et = ...;
Drawable back = et.getBackground();
back.setColorFilter(NEEDED_CLR, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
et.setBackground(back);  //requires API 16
```

Is there any programmatical alternative for ICS?

Comment: you should have several drawable background for each widget's state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `edittext.setBackgroundDrawable(background)`

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_test);
Drawable background = text.getBackground();
background.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_A100), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
   text.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
} else {
   text.setBackground(background);
}
```

this work in all api level but deprecated in api level 16(ICS)

Comment: Yeah. Just discovered that `setBackground(Drawable)` simply calls deprecated `setBackgroundDrawable()`. Strange thing